# Photographer - Need a gallery script

Tags: photography, gallery

I need a script that will present my images in a way similar to pixieset or flickr (the set of pictures dynamically fit to the browser width, etc.), that will also, like them, allow you to view a larger version of the image.

Free or paid, as long as paid doesn't have a recurring fee.

It needs to automatically create thumbnails for my pictures, or have succinct implementation of resizes that I have to do manually.

I use XAMPP via Windows-7, but may use a third party host later. Also, I prefer PHP, MySQL, JS/JQ.

Suggestions?

(I asked a similar question before but did not get any good responses. I tried to delete that question but couldn't. Anyway, I made this question much more simple and clear.)

Comment: If for setup/maintenance the thing needs a desktop variant (which often is the case), what OS must be supported for this? Furthermore, any preferences server-side (e.g. PHP, or whatever your web server supports)?

Comment: @Izzy I use XAMPP via w7, but may use a third party host later. As far as I understand, there's usually no significant difference between xampp and using linux+apache? ... Also, I prefer PHP, MySQL, JS/JQ. And I hate WYSIWYG editors, I'd rather not use a program for setup etc.

Comment: Thanks for the update (integrated it with your question). My father (master photographer) just started using something that sounds like it fits your needs, and is quite enthusiastic with it. Need to ask him for the name (was something like Pixtacy, so maybe this one: [Pixtacy](http://www.pixtacy.de/)). As for XAMPP: I don't know much about the Windows part (usually called WAMP I thought?), but the Linux one is often referred to as LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP).